# How do items in an object from one function transfer into another function?

Tags: react-redux, redux-thunk

I am learning react redux, I am using `firebase` for storing data.

I installed thunk middleware. Everything works, I just don't understand why.

As I understand it, the const expense is an object which is in another function's scope. How can `addExpense` gets access to it?

```
export const addExpense = (expense) => ({
    type: 'ADD_EXPENSE',
    expense
});

export const startAddExpense = (expenseData = {}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const {
            description = '',
            note = '',
            amount = 0,
            createdAt = 0
        } = expenseData;
        const expense = { description, note, amount, createdAt };

        database.ref('expenses').push(expense).then((ref) => {
            dispatch(addExpense({
                id: ref.key,
                ...expense
            }));
        });
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startAddExpense` is passing the `const expense` object to your `addExpense` function, along with an `id` field. It just so happens that the argument to `addExpense` is also called `expense`, which is where you might be getting confused.

Hope that clears it up.

Comment: I have just figured out this morning, for some reasons I did not see it yesterday, because of the dispatch, I can pass the object to addExpense, but after a good night of sleep, I can see things clearer. thanks